# Online tool for IPA pronunciation synthesis

Tags: phonology, phonetics, ipa, software, tools

I've already found [this tool from 0n0e.com](https://www.0n0e.com/public/phoneme-synthesis/) but the problem is that it pronounces the words too quickly. Is there any other phoneme synthesis online which speaks a bit slower?

Comment: Do you need *all* of the IPA? Or only a subset? (I don't know any system which can do the *entire* IPA, since there's a *lot* of phones out there.)

Comment: @Draconis Well, my brother and me are trying to make a constructed language as a hobby. So I want the major amount of IPA sounds as possible. We need the phoneme synthetiser in order to understand that sounds and hear them.

Comment: Ah, you might find the Wikipedia charts with audio helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_pulmonic_consonant_chart_with_audio https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio

Answer (score 5):

The linked page is prominently open source. You can probably download the sources to your own computer and tweak the parameters to make it speak more slowly. It links to http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/ which displays detailed controls for amplitude, pitch, speed, word gap, etc. The same controls are hardcoded into `mespeak.js` in the fragment `$speed=175;$amp=100;$wordgap=0` so you can probably simply edit that in-place. I have not looked into how hard it is to install required dependencies etc to make it actually run on your own web server (or even, gasp, in a local file with no server).